# Invalid syntax inside of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Working on a programming puzzle. Question asks to use `string.maketrans()` to solve the problem. code goes like this:

```
from string import maketrans
inup = "k"
outup = "o"
codee = maketrans(k, o)
string a = " g fmnc wms bgblr rpylqjyrc gr zw fylb. rfyrq ufyr amknsrcpq ypc dmp. bmgle gr gl zw fylb gq glcddgagclr ylb rfyr'q ufw rfgq rcvr gq qm jmle. sqgle qrpgle.kyicrpylq() gq pcamkkclbcb. lmu ynnjw ml rfc spj."
print a.translate(codee)
```

Error (in python2.7 & 3) is:
`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

I'm rusty with my python and didn't even know the inside of a string was checked for syntax issues. What's the workaround here?

Comment: Change `string a = ...` to `a = ...`  Python has no `string` keyword.

Comment: If you wanted to note the type, the syntax would be `a: str = . . .` (assuming a recent version of Python 3). That hints the type, but doesn't enforce it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python,you don't have to declare a varable,so the "string a=..." is wrong, replace it with "a=..."

And,in python 3.x,print is not a keyword,you will have to use "print(xxx)" and not "print xxx".